# Can I hide some content in a page from Google's indexing? (need more recent answer)

Tags: javascript, seo, googlebot

Having looked at some old (2009) questions, I anticipate the answer is no, but I can't find a recent enough definitive answer, so I'm asking again...

I have some JavaScript-enabled tabs on a page which can be automatically pre-selected by passing a parameter in the query string like this:

```
www.example.com/landing-page?tab=tab1
```

Is there a way to prevent Google from indexing content in the tabs that are not currently visible? Also, I'd need it to treat the URL as a different page if a different tab is specified in the query string.

**Update:** I understand according to [this page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550) that you can set specific parameters to be considered unique pages based on the parameter having different values. So now the only question is whether or not it's possible to hide content on a page from Googlebot. According to some old answers, it sounds like probably not, but again, I'm looking for an up-to-date officially documented answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no official documentation to this specific issue but it depends on the type of content you have for each tab.

If the content of each tabs are links you can add rel="nofollow" tag.

If you're displaying resources on the tabs like images, pdf... you can setup a robots.txt to block Google from accessing it.

Example:

```
disallow: /images
disallow: /pdf
```

But if you want to block Googlebot to access certain texts inside a page then it would be impossible to do because Google will fetch all the resources on a given page. Unless if you block Google on the page level